# SQL How to combine multiple rows with same post_id into one using response values to create columns

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm pretty sure my problem has very simple solution and was asked somewhere before, so I believe it's not big deal for you to help me.

First of all I have query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id = 340 
AND (
     meta_key = '_regular_price' 
     OR meta_key = 'multiplier' 
     OR meta_key = 'multiplier_filter' 
     OR meta_key = 'price_filter' 
     OR meta_key = 'attribute_size' 
     OR meta_key = 'live_update'
    );
```

So as you can see I work with wordpress and everything here works but I would like to change interpretation of the response.

Now it looks like:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8197 | 200 | price | 100 |
| 9209 | 200 | filter | 2 |
| 9208 | 200 | update | true |

But it would be ideal if it starts giving response in this format:

| post_id | price | filter | update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 100 | 2 | true |

Comment: Does `(post_id, meta_key)` is defined as UNIQUE? if not then what should be returned for the rows group with the same expression value?

Comment: @Akina, I've already got answer. Thanks to Tim!

Comment: If the expression above is not UNIQUE then you may get the wrong result that is expected.

Comment: They are UNIQUE for each post_id

Comment: I don't ask does they ARE unique, I ask does they are DEFINED as unique in the table structure. If not then they may have non-unique value (for example as a result of minor error or after errorneous direct data edition).

Comment: No column isn't defined as unique and as it is standard wordpress table I cannot do this because some functions uses non-unique factor of this table. So the only way not to make errors or somehow sort them

Comment: This is the point which I mean. For example, your entity have 2 (or more) rows with different prices - Tim's answer will give you the greatest of them whereas you may need in, for example, the latest... You must take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'price'  THEN meta_value END) AS price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'filter' THEN meta_value END) AS filter,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'update' THEN meta_value END) AS `update`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY post_id;
```